# Mac OS /User folder permissions and ownership

Tags: permissions, osx

What is default /Users folder owner and group and permissions?

Yesterday I installed VirtualBox with Homebrew and had some issues with that, but after success, I got some warning in my zsh terminal with some ruby script which was saying after any command that /Users folder has to much privileges.

I have tried fix home folder permissions etc. but my /Users folder owner is my user and group is stuff. In privileges it has read for everyone and staff.

Is it ok ?

Comment: Please include the exact warning that you get along with the output of `ls -ld "$HOME"`. [Edit] the question rather than adding the information in a comment.

Comment: This question would be more appropriate for [apple.se], since it's specific to Mac OS, not Unix in general.

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but:

The `/Users` folder should be owned by `root:admin` and have `755` permissions.

Each `/Users/<USERNAME>` folder should be owned by `<USERNAME>:staff` and have `700` permissions.